# jQuery accordion slideToggle problem

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have an accordion where html loads live via ajax in a div. The div has a close button where you can remove it from dom when its clicked. When the div is created again without reloading the page then the slideToggle triggers twice up and down and then hides the content.

Here is html loaded via ajax:

```
<div id="slidetoggle">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>content</p>

  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>content</p>

  *..and so on..*

 </div>
```

Here is jquery:

```
$("#slidetoggle p:not(:first)").hide();

$("#slidetoggle h3").live('click', function(){
  $(this).next("p").slideToggle("slow").siblings("p:visible").slideUp("slow");
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update: The number of times slideToggle triggers on the selected h3 increases by the times I remove and create the div where html is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.die()](http://api.jquery.com/die/) when remove nodes from DOM.

Comment: $("#slidetoggle h3").die('click'); fiexed the problem, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use jquery ui accordian.

Have a look http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $(document).off('click', '#slidetoggle h3').on('click', '#slidetoggle h3',function(e) {
   ...
 }
```